# Image loaded from TGA texture isn't displayed correctly

Tags: opengl, textures, c

I have a TGA texture containing this image:

[image]

The texture is 256x256. 
So I'm trying to load it and map it to a cube:

```
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <assert.h>


GLuint width=640, height=480;
GLuint texture;
const char* const filename= "/Users/ramy/Documents/C/OpenGL/Test/Test/texture.tga";




void init()
{

    // Initialization

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(-500, -500, 1000, 1000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, width/(float)height, 1, 1000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    // Texture

    char bitmap[256][256][3];
    FILE* fp=fopen(filename, "r");
    assert(fp);
    assert(fread(bitmap, 3*sizeof(char), 256*256, fp) == 256*256);
    fclose(fp);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap);

}


void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);

    glVertex3f(40, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(40, 40, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(0, 40, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

But this is what I get when the window loads:

[image]

So just half of the image is correctly displayed, and also with different colors.Then if I resize the window I get this:

[image]

Magically the image seems to fix itself, even if the colors are wrong.Why?

Comment: The first one looks like an error with your texture coordinates (`glTexCoord2f`). Though, why that would be fixed by re-sizing, I have no idea. Especially since you're doing immediate mode rendering.

Comment: Maybe theres more to the code were not seeing

Comment: That's all the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is the order in which you specify your vertices and texture coordinates:

```
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
```

should be:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
```

OpenGL is a state machine, and in immediate mode, whenever you call `glVertex3f` the vertex will take on the different attributes (color, texture coordinates, etc.) currently set.  The very first vertex that you specify, you have not set texture coordinates, so it will get `(0,0)`.  Then you actually call `glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f)`, and so your second vertex also has texture coordinates of `(0,0)`.  This leads to the distortion.

Now, since you are not calling `glutPostRedisplay` anywhere, the `display` function will not be called until it actually needs to be, which happens to be when you resize the window.  This time around, your first vertex will have the last texture coordinates that you sent through `glTexCoord2f`, namely:

```
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
```

which you set in the *previous* call to `update`.  On this frame though, each vertex gets different texture coordinates, so the texture looks normal (but it will actually be rotated).